# What is the recommended way to deploy a node app on FreeBSD in 2021?

Tags: freebsd, node.js

Basically I want to deploy a node application on FreeBSD 12.

Ideally I'd prefer to build it on one system, and install it in production separately, so as to install as few development tools on the server as possible.  Then I'd like to arrange that this application run as a service in the most FreeBSD canonical manner possible.

I've read a few tutorials on how to do this and depending on when they were published, they seem to recommend all sorts of approaches: pm12, passenger, forever.

The application in question is: https://github.com/Akkadius/glass-isc-dhcp

As you might have already guessed, I don't have much experience with node at all.

Comment: Probably with an rc.d script, and that is [not necessarily trivial](https://docs.freebsd.org/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/rc-scripting/article.html) as it would be with modern Linux.

Comment: Yeah, the rc.d part of it I'm fine with.  It's the node toolchain that I'm not sure about. npm, where do the packages get installed, can I get it to install in one directory, do I need home directories...? etc

Comment: You can use `py-supervisord` instead of a plain rc.d script.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I would put writing a rc.d script up against so-called "modern Linux" any minute of any day and have BSD spit in Linux' face when it's running.